# When i am trying to use filter function in R it shows object not found

Tags: r

[image: Blockquote]

```
Error in filter(Balance > 50, Balance < 100) : object 'Balance' not found
```

Comment: `filter(YOUR_DATA, Balance > 50, Balance < 100)` or `YOUR_DATA %>% filter(Balance > 50, Balance < 100)`

Comment: you should pass the data.frame to the filter function

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it through something (dataframe) before you apply the filter

Try:

```
df %>%
  filter(Balance > 50, Balance < 100)
```

where df is your dataframe name

Answer (score 0):

An option with `subset`

```
subset(df, Balance > 50  & Balance < 100)
```